# CONSULTA ANIDADA SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hola espero puedan ayudarme Me encuentro en la fase final de desarrollar una aplicación para laboratorio
y estoy estancado. El punto es que necesito generar un PDF con valores normales y el resultado del estudio.
entonces en  la tabla 1 tengo Estos datos que siempre va ir fijos pero solo si el la otra tabla tiene esa id
Necesito hacer una consulta que me una dos tablas

la primera tabla **COTIZADOR** contiene **VAR, NOMBRE,REFERENCIAL,TIPOENTRADA** LA COLUMNA VAR CONTIENE EL NOMBRE DE LAS COLUMNA EN LA TABLA **LABSANGRE**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la segunda tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es fragmento de la consulta que he intentado.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM cotizador 
      WHERE var = (Select  COLUMN_NAME 
                   From labsangre 
                   Where id = '$idfactura')"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

entonces quisiera hacer una sola tabla en una sola consulta que que he intentado hacer varias consultas por separado a través de funciones en php con retorno y no me sale muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido. Procura evitar el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas; se asimila a que estás gritando y no es la idea. :)

Comment: Como ya ha señalado @Alfabravo, cuida un poco la redacción de tu pregunta. En vez de imágenes se agradece que muestres el contenido, **en texto** de lo que arroja un `SHOW CREATE TABLE aquiNombreDeLaTabla;` de cada una de tus tablas y explícanos cómo se relacionan. También, muéstanos lo que has intentado, qué resultados/errores tienes y danos un ejemplo pequeño de lo que quieres obtener. Así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No te recomiendo usar solo una tabla esto te generará mas problemas que soluciones, en bases de datos lo mas recomendable es no repetir datos, te recomiendo que leas Formas Normales, y con respecto a tu problema veo que no tienes FK entre tus tablas, por eso la complicación para encontrar una relación, el id identifica al registro, pero no su relación con otra tabla si hubieses tenido este campo con un simple Join obtendrías la respuesta. (yo también trabajo en lab) .

Comment: @RobertoPaillao Te agradeceria mucho que me des una idea en esto muchas gracias o ejemplificación Saludos!!

Comment: @JosuéAcostaCastro Como dice Roberto, lo mejor es que uses varias tablas que se relacionen entre si, para eso, puedes aprender un poco más sobre como usar llaves foraneas. De esa manera puedes usar la sentencia JOIN en mysql para unir ambas tablas y usar los datos que necesites.

Prueba leyendo este artículo para que aprendas más al respecto.

https://ingsystemas.webnode.es/bases-de-datos/llaves-primarias-y-foraneas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno en base a lo que solicitas, deberías tener una tabla de resultados y otra tabla de tipos de análisis ademas de la tabla cotizador que supongo es para realizar una cotización de los análisis solicitados, en la tabla análisis deberían estar ingresados todos lo tipos de análisis que realiza tu laboratorio, junto con el valor y otro atributos inherentes a el mismo cada una de estas tablas debería estar relacionada a través de una FK ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cotización tiene valor solo como oferta al cliente y este puede tomarla o no, pero una vez que es aceptada ya pasa a ser una orden de análisis, y en base a este esquema podemos hacer varios tipos de consulta, observa que la tabla análisis obtendrá todos los análisis realizados por el laboratorio y estos podrán ser usados tanto en cotizaciones como en ordenes de análisis y también en resultados de esta manera no tienes que estar repitiendo registros tan solo debes ver la manera en que se relacionan a través de sus FK's.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `lab` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `lab` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lab`.`analisis`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lab`.`analisis` (
  `idanalisis` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `codigo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `costo` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idanalisis`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lab`.`clientes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lab`.`clientes` (
  `idclientes` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `DNI` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idclientes`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lab`.`cotizaciones`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lab`.`cotizaciones` (
  `idcotizacion` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `clientes_idclientes` INT NOT NULL,
  `analisis_idanalisis` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcotizacion`),
  INDEX `fk_cotizaciones_clientes1_idx` (`clientes_idclientes` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_cotizaciones_analisis1_idx` (`analisis_idanalisis` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cotizaciones_clientes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientes_idclientes`)
    REFERENCES `lab`.`clientes` (`idclientes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cotizaciones_analisis1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`analisis_idanalisis`)
    REFERENCES `lab`.`analisis` (`idanalisis`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lab`.`resultados`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lab`.`resultados` (
  `idresultados` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `valor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `analisis_idanalisis` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idresultados`, `analisis_idanalisis`),
  INDEX `fk_resultados_analisis1_idx` (`analisis_idanalisis` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_resultados_analisis1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`analisis_idanalisis`)
    REFERENCES `lab`.`analisis` (`idanalisis`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lab`.`orden_analisis`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lab`.`orden_analisis` (
  `idorden_analisis` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `fecha` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `clientes_idclientes` INT NOT NULL,
  `analisis_idanalisis` INT NOT NULL,
  `resultados_idresultados` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idorden_analisis`),
  INDEX `fk_orden_analisis_clientes1_idx` (`clientes_idclientes` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_orden_analisis_analisis1_idx` (`analisis_idanalisis` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_orden_analisis_resultados1_idx` (`resultados_idresultados` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orden_analisis_clientes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientes_idclientes`)
    REFERENCES `lab`.`clientes` (`idclientes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orden_analisis_analisis1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`analisis_idanalisis`)
    REFERENCES `lab`.`analisis` (`idanalisis`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orden_analisis_resultados1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`resultados_idresultados`)
    REFERENCES `lab`.`resultados` (`idresultados`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `lab`.`analisis` (`idanalisis`, `nombre`, `codigo`, `costo`) VALUES ('1', 'Leucocitos', 'LEUC', '15000');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`analisis` (`idanalisis`, `nombre`, `codigo`, `costo`) VALUES ('2', 'Hemoglobina', 'HEMOG', '25000');

INSERT INTO `lab`.`clientes` (`idclientes`, `nombre`, `DNI`) VALUES ('1', 'Denis Ritchie', '11111111');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`clientes` (`idclientes`, `nombre`, `DNI`) VALUES ('2', 'Ken Thompson', '2222222');

INSERT INTO `lab`.`resultados` (`idresultados`, `valor`, `analisis_idanalisis`) VALUES ('1', '0.8', '1');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`resultados` (`idresultados`, `valor`, `analisis_idanalisis`) VALUES ('2', '0.7', '2');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`resultados` (`idresultados`, `valor`, `analisis_idanalisis`) VALUES ('3', '0.5', '2');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`resultados` (`idresultados`, `valor`, `analisis_idanalisis`) VALUES ('4', '0.6', '1');

INSERT INTO `lab`.`cotizaciones` (`idcotizacion`, `numero`, `clientes_idclientes`, `analisis_idanalisis`) VALUES ('1', '0001', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`cotizaciones` (`idcotizacion`, `numero`, `clientes_idclientes`, `analisis_idanalisis`) VALUES ('2', '0002', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`cotizaciones` (`idcotizacion`, `numero`, `clientes_idclientes`, `analisis_idanalisis`) VALUES ('3', '0003', '2', '2');

INSERT INTO `lab`.`orden_analisis` (`idorden_analisis`, `numero`, `fecha`, `clientes_idclientes`, `analisis_idanalisis`, `resultados_idresultados`) VALUES ('1', '0001', '2020-08-28', '1', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`orden_analisis` (`idorden_analisis`, `numero`, `fecha`, `clientes_idclientes`, `analisis_idanalisis`, `resultados_idresultados`) VALUES ('2', '0002', '2020-08-28', '1', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `lab`.`orden_analisis` (`idorden_analisis`, `numero`, `fecha`, `clientes_idclientes`, `analisis_idanalisis`, `resultados_idresultados`) VALUES ('3', '0003', '2020-08-28', '2', '1', '3');
```

Te muestro un par de ejemplos de consultas para que los verifiques :

```
-- Obtener todas las ordenes de analisis de Denis Ritchie
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    orden_analisis o
        LEFT JOIN
    clientes c ON o.clientes_idclientes = c.idclientes
WHERE
    c.nombre LIKE '%Denis%'; 

-- obtener todas los resultados de la orden de análisis 0003
-- incluido el nombre del cliente y nombre del análisis 
SELECT 
    o.numero,
    o.fecha,
    a.nombre,
    r.valor,
    c.nombre
FROM
    resultados r
        LEFT JOIN
    orden_analisis o ON o.resultados_idresultados = r.idresultados
        LEFT JOIN 
     analisis a ON o.analisis_idanalisis=a.idanalisis 
        LEFT JOIN 
     clientes c ON o.clientes_idclientes=c.idclientes
WHERE
    o.numero = '0003';
```

Espero que este pequeño ejemplo te sirva, es solo para explicar de manera básica las FK's, dependiendo de la complejidad del sistema las consultas se pueden complejizar un poco, pero para eso estamos nosotros.  Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @RobertoPaillao; He utilizado varias  funciones que hacen consultas y envían datos a otra función.

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudara a optimizar el tiempo de carga de resultados Saludos!!